# Communication between nested components in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout custom elements in my application, but I'm stuck with one problem. I have two nested custom elements and I want them to communicate. I tried to share observable between them, but I'm constantly getting an error: `Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { nodes:$componentTemplateNodes} } Message: someVariable is not defined` - inner component can't access observable. How to fix this? Or maybe there is a better way to communicate between nested components? I'm using knockout 3.3.0

my code:

**html:**

```
<parent-component params="variable: someVariable">
    <child-component params="variable: someVariable"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

**js:**

```
ko.components.register("parent-component", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.params = params;
    },
    template: "<div data-bind='text: params.variable'></div> <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->"
});

ko.components.register("child-component", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.params = params;
    },
    template: "<div data-bind='text: params.variable'></div>"
});

ko.applyBindings({
    someVariable: ko.observable(true)
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/50zbtxe3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that "someVariable" does not exist inside the "parent-component".
You should pass it to the next binding level:

```
ko.components.register("parent-component", {
viewModel: function (params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.someVariable = params.variable;
},
template: "<div data-bind='text: params.variable'></div> <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->"
});
```

I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50zbtxe3/1/

Answer (score 4):

One more option is to use the future **let** binding which will be coming out with in a later iteration of knockout. This would allow you to do the following in the grandparent component:

```
<!-- ko let: { $parentComponent: $component } -->
<parent-component params="variable: $component.someVariable">
    <child-component params="variable: $parentComponent.someVariable"></child-component>
</parent-component>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Basically allowing you to get access to a parent component from another component.

The let binding code can be found here:
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/binding/defaultBindings/let.js

Comment: I have never seen this binding before, what version is it coming out in?

Comment: Checking github releases looks like the target is 3.5.0 as it was included in that beta
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.5.0-beta

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend bind nested template to the `$parent` scope if you need just simple container

```js
ko.components.register("parent-container", {
viewModel: function (params) {
    this.params = params;
},
template: "<div data-bind='style: { color: params.color }'>Header</div> <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, data: $parent } --><!-- /ko -->"
});

var model = {
  someVariable: 'test'
}

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<parent-container params="color: 'red'">
  <div data-bind="text: someVariable">asdasdsad</div>
</parent-container>

<parent-container params="color: 'blue'">
  <div data-bind="text: someVariable2">asdasdsad</div>
</parent-container>
```

Comment: Best answer by far. Simple, kept within the wrapping component so that children aren't having to deal with parent layout. Love this!

Comment: Thanks, @k2snowman69 work too many times with complicated solutions written by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `DataContext` of the `child-component` is not the root viewmodel. So you have to reference the root viewmodel directly. Like this:

```
<parent-component params="variable: someVariable">
    <child-component params="variable: $root.someVariable"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

The context of `child-component` is the `viewmodel` of the `parent-component`, which does not have a `someVariable` property.